# Ubuntu on Alienware m14x

Tags: alienware

i had used linux once when i was 8 back in 2001 and i used to love it as i played the games that came with the OS, then i left linux until recently since i have been hearing about all this new linux hype so i decided to give it a try.

I have used this OS since one semester now, It lives upto its hype and i am seriously in love with it and i had downloaded wine and have been playing games on it even tho all my games do not work "I'll remain patient and hope it soon becomes better"

Now the only Issue with the operating system is that the games i used to play was slower, then i went to settings and details and noticed that the laptop was using Intel instead of Nvidia GPU and optimus was not supported. I understand that there might be some devs here and experts so could any one write a tutorial for serious noobs it would help me and all the new people starting to use linux.

Also i wonder why ubuntu devs do not integrate Wine into the OS ?.

"Sorry for my english and also if i had asked a question that already had been answered as i didn't find any of them fit to work for my laptop, i bricked the OS multiple times"

P.S i also always get an error when i boot the OS and unity shows.

Comment: How to use this site: 1 problem = 1 question. Provide error messages, if you have any. Search for them before asking a question, this might **save you your time**.

Answer (score 0):

Wine stands for windows emulator. The reason it is not integrated into the OS is that people do not use ubuntu to run windows applications. If you browse the software centre, you can find that there are replacements for every application that you use on windows.

Wine cannot run every windows game on linux no matter how long you wait. Waiting for steam would be a better option. There already some [linux games](http://store.steampowered.com/browse/linux/) released for steam.

Nvidia optimus is not supported on linux for the time being - thanks to Nvidia. But a driver is expected in the upcoming releases.